# Gracefull shutdown on Jboss server 7

Tags: spring, jboss

I have a scenario where i need to perform a gracefull shutdown on Jboss server 7 where my application needs to flush out all Objects from My application with proper logging and deleting out all the active session containing in my application . I am using spring 3.0 is there any thing provided by spring framework for this

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an `ApplicationListener` or use a servlet context lifecycle listener instead:

- [Application context event handling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events)
- [Servlet context event handling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000654)